# Analysis of psychology/sociology of fashion?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, sociology

I'm looking for some good place to start read about sociology of fashion. I guess there are some researches about why people "invented" fashion and is it some natural for human as a biological species or it is accidentally happened social phenomenon.

Is there some social functions of fashion? I suppose that from the anti-capitalism point of view fashion cult is a just a consequence of consumer society, but maybe there some scientific studies of psychology and sociology of fashion and it's social functions?

Comment: Welcome. How do you define fashion? And it would be good [necessary] to focus the question on the psychology-side-of-things. we are not a sociology stack, but specific a stack on cognition, psychology and neuroscience.

Answer (score -1):

Mair, C. (2019). Speaking of Psychology: Psychology of Fashion. Retrieved August 25, 2020, from https://www.apa.org/research/action/speaking-of-psychology/fashion